# AutoCompleteTextView not showing any drop down items when apk installed using Appium

Tags: android, automation, appium, autocompletetextview

I'm new to Appium Mobile Automation tool.

**Server version:** 1.4.16.1

**OS:** Windows 7

**What I'm Doing:** Actually the way Appium is installing apk on my Android device its changing the behavior of App. Eg: AutoCompletetextview not showing suggestions when apk is installed via Appium otherwise it behaves perfectly when App is installed manually.

When App is Installed manually "AutoCompletetextview" works very well. You can see the picture below

[image: Automated appium]

But When App is Installed via Appium/ If I set these parameters

> capabilities.setCapability("noReset","true");
>
> capabilities.setCapability("fullReset","false");

AutoCompletetextview doesn't show any suggestions.

[image: Maually-pic]

**What i Want to acheive** : I want to select the suggestions from Autocompletetextview.

Find the Code below

```
package appium_project_two;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class StoreCreditBill {

    // create global array list containing barcodes
    static String strBarcodeList[] = { "1" };

    // create global variable
    private static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        // Create object of DesiredCapabilities class

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        // to avoid installing app again and again
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        // to avoid installing app again and again
        capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "false");

        // Optional

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

        // Specify the device name (any name)

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Bewo Genie POS");

        // Platform version

        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");

        // platform name

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        // specify the application package that we copied from appium

        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.bewo.retails");

        // specify the Bewo Application activity that you want to access

        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".activities.HomeScreen");

        // Start android driver I used 4727 port by default it will be 4723

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        // passing the barcode 
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.bewo.retails:id/txtAutoSearch_Billing")).sendKeys(strBarcodeList[0] + "\n");

        // waiting for some time
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // passing customer name
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.bewo.retails:id/txtAutoCPhone_Billing")).sendKeys("Saurabh");

        //waiting for some time
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // trying to click on the exact place where the AutoTextview List will populate
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.bewo.retails:id/chkHomeDelivery")).click();

        // waiting again for sometime
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // pressing the Quickpay Button
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.bewo.retails:id/btnQuickPay_Billing")).click();

        // pressing the Quick Return Button
//      driver.findElement(By.id("com.bewo.retails:id/btnQuickReturn_Billing")).click();


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("got interrupted!");
        }
        // close the application
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Comment: add the complete page source of the application window.